# Find out if a specific Android app was previously installed

Tags: android

I have an App which provides you a list of various apps that you can download and install from Play Store to earn goodies. Now, I don't want a user to **uninstall** a previously installed app and **download it again** through my app and earn goodies.

**Is there a way to find out if a specific app was previously installed on the user's device?**

**Update**
I am interested in all the apps installed/uninstalled, regardless of when my app was installed. I don't want to store any data about any app installs on my end, I want to know if this data is already stored on the device somewhere for further reference.

**Note**
I am also interested in the apps that we uninstalled. Can I get this data too?

Answer (score 7):

I can see where you are trying to go, but I think you need to rethink the approach a bit. You should always allow your users to install and uninstall as they wish. But you can put a check in the app to see when the app was first installed.

```
PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
long firstInstallTime = info.firstInstallTime;
```

This will store the time the app was first installed in `firstInstallTime` 
This time stamp will not change with any number of subsequent uninstalls and re-installs.

The [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) class provides a bunch of other useful info about your app on the device and is well worth getting to know.

You can compare this to the timestamp when the apps source directory was last modified (in other words when the app was most recent installed), which you can obtain with:

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
long mostRecentInstallTime = new File(appInfo.sourceDir).lastModified();
```

I've also used this approach to give users a 1 week trial of an apps full features before reverting to the lesser "free mode", and they can't trip it up by uninstalling and re-installing.

---

Additional:
In response to your comment...
You are not just restricted to getting PackageInfo for your own app or apps installed after yours was. You can get PackageInfo for all apps currently on the device, regardless of when they were installed in the "devices lifetime".
This slightly modified version of the code found [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon) will give you the firstInstallTime for all apps on the device:

```
// Get PackageInfo for each app on the device
List<PackageInfo> packageInfoInstalledPackages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

// Now iterate through to get the info you need.
long[] firstInstallTimes = long[packageInfoInstalledPackages.size()];
for(int i=0;i<packageInfoInstalledPackages.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packageInfoInstalledPackages.get(i);
    if (p.versionName != null) {
        firstInstallTimes[i] = p.firstInstallTime;
    }        
}
```

You can also get the `ApplicationInfo` so you should have all you need.

Comment: I think this can be done only after my app is installed and I'll be able to only track those apps that are installed/uninstalled after my app was installed. Now, I want to track all the installs in the device's lifetime. So basically I am interested in all the apps installed/uninstalled, regardless of when my app was installed.

Comment: See the "Additional" to my answer.

Comment: Ok again, I am also interested in the apps that we uninstalled. Can I get this data too?

Comment: Hmm.. logically for android to be able to retrieve a firstInstallTime, it must keep a list somewhere of the package names and first install times after they've been uninstalled. The method I've listed has always been sufficient for my needs, but if you definitely need to access such a list and there is no other alternative, then start digging through the android source code to see how they store this information. That's the beauty of an open source OS. You can look at the source and see how it all works. Good luck.

Comment: This answer is wrong, firstInstallTime is reset if the app is uninstalled and reinstalled.

Comment: @Patrick, you are incorrect. I have used and tested fisrtInstallTime in my commercial apps, and it works as per the official google documentation. A quick search will also show that this is the standard approach used for this sort of problem.

Comment: @SoundConception A quick test will show that this does not work. Uninstall and reinstall the app and firstInstallTime is reset.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will log all the main activities of the apps installed on you device, you just have to check that list for a given app

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List <ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);

for(ResolveInfo resolve : pkgAppsList)
{
    Log.d("MY_APP", resolve.toString());
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Firstly, Thankx! Now, this gives me a list of apps that are currently installed on the system, but is there a way to find out apps that were installed prior but are not present at the given moment?