# How do applications know that device has already installed the app and eliminates it from referral bonus?

Tags: android, kotlin, settings

There are many online payment applications such as paytm, phonepe, Google pay.we do have different referral programs in these respective payment applications. After signing up for an account in the device when we try to create another account in the same device by clearing the application data, we are not getting any referral bonus. How do these apps know that the respective mobile has already used for the application and its not eligible for the referral program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out if a specific Android app was previously installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735672/find-out-if-a-specific-android-app-was-previously-installed)

Comment: check this link hope it will help https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158508/how-do-some-android-apps-remember-that-this-is-not-the-first-time-they-are-being

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Google pay encrypts and stores a unique device account number on a dedicated chip on your device. And probably also it saves a Unique Device ID for each devices that installed Google Pay. 
FYI: You can link two banks accounts on Google Pay if that is what you want.